# Django - Saving in multiple models from single API

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I have two models, "Blog_model" and "File_model" where "blog_id" of "Blog_model" is the foreign key for "File_Model". The concept is to save multiple files for a single blog. Here is the model structure for reference.

```
class Blog_model(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = "FOOD")
    count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500, unique = True)
    substance = models.CharField(max_length = 5000, default = "")
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_media_file_name, default = "")
    text = models.TextField()
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)


class File_model(models.Model):
    blog_id = models.ForeignKey(Blog_model, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to = get_media_file_name)
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file_name)
```

Now, I want to create a new blog using a single API that will have details of blogs, as well as file names. I am imagining the API structure something like -

```
{
"type": "FOOD",
"title": "Some Blog",
"Substance": "Some blog about food",
"text": "This is some blog about food",
"thumbnail": <InMemoryUploadedFile: Capture.PNG (image/png)>
"files": [<InMemoryUploadedFile: food1.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: food2.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: food3.jpg (image/jpeg)>]
}
```

Please suggest how to achieve the goal.
You may suggest a correct API structure also if above mentioned seems to be wrong.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
This is the serializer and view I am using for this purpose.

```
-----------------------------------
serializers.py
-----------------------------------

class File_modelCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # upload_time = serializers.DateTimeField(format = date_time_format)

    class Meta:
        model = File_model
        fields = ["file_name"]


class Blog_modelCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = File_modelCreateSerializer(many = True, required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog_model
        fields = ["type", "title", "substance", "thumbnail", "text", "files"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # files = validated_data.pop("files")       # Getting no key named "files" in validated_data
        new_blog = Blog_model.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # for f in files:
        #     File_model.objects.create(blog_id = new_blog, **f)

        return new_blog


-----------------------------------
views.py
-----------------------------------

# class Blog_modelCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):   
#     serializer_class = Blog_modelCreateSerializer

class Blog_modelCreateView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        blog_serializer = Blog_modelCreateSerializer(data = request.data)
        if blog_serializer.is_valid():
            blog_serializer.save()
            return Response(blog_serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(blog_serializer.errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, View and Serializer are linked to a model.
But, you can use `@action` decorator.

See [Django REST Framework: Routing for extra actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions)

If you want to link File serializer to Blog, try this.

```
class BlogViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def get_serializer(self):
        if self.action == 'files':
           return FileSerializer
    ...
    @action(url_path='files')
    def file(self):
        qs = File.objects.all()
        ...
```